# Dealing with frequent updates to a large React component

Tags: reactjs

I have a large React component with scrollbars. I'd like to make some small changes to a few components when it scrolls (basically to keep the left-most column of a table stuck to the left side of the screen).

Normally I'd pass props indicating the component's scroll position down to the components that need to update when it scrolls, but re-rendering the whole component when it scrolls makes the whole thing massively laggy. But the whole thing doesn't really need to be re-rendered -- only a few small parts of it to make sure they stay in the right part of the screen

Is there a good way to re-render only a small part of a component, or is there another way of dealing with frequent updates to large components like this?

Answer (score 0):

Implementation might get a bit hairy but have you had a look into `shouldComponentUpdate`? ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate))

You could probably track the scrolling and use it to skip updating on the pieces you don't want to update - eg. pass an `isScrolling` prop to some children and skip update if it's true, or only update if the scoll distance has changed by a certain amount or a certain amount of time has passed.

Depending on the visual effect you want another option is to replace the content of the slow part with a placeholder which is more easily rendered  when the `isScrolling` prop is set - we do something similar with an `isLoading` prop and loading GIFs, which works well.